# reactstrap close Nav when link clicked

Tags: reactstrap

I'm sure this has been asked before however, I can't find the answer. How do you get the `Nav` menu to close when you click on a `NavLink` in reactstrap or is this still in development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reactstrap has an `isOpen` parameter in state, so you need to set it to `false`

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.closeNavbar = this.closeNavbar.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    closeNavbar() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        });
    }

    // and in Link or a element add onClick handler like this


    <Link to="/" onClick={closeNavbar}>Home</Link>
```

Here is the code I use:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import library from './FontAwesomeLibrary';
import logo from '../../assets/images/logo.svg';

import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    Nav,
    NavItem } from 'reactstrap';

class Topbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.closeNavbar = this.closeNavbar.bind(this);
        this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: false,
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }
    closeNavbar() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false
        });
    }
    handleClickOutside(event) {
        const t = event.target;
        if (this.state.isOpen && !t.classList.contains('navbar-toggler')) {
            this.closeNavbar();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="topbar">
                <section className="container">
                    <Navbar color="light" className="header" expand="md">
                        <Link className="locoLink" to="/"><img src={logo} className="logo" alt="logo" /></Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="logoCompany">Redux Blog</Link>
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={this.state.isOpen ? "times" : "bars"}/>
                        </NavbarToggler>
                        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                            <Nav className="ml-auto routes" navbar>
                                <NavItem>
                                    <Link to="/" onClick={this.closeNavbar}>Posts</Link>
                                </NavItem>
                                <NavItem>
                                    <Link to="/posts/new" onClick={this.closeNavbar}>New Post</Link>
                                </NavItem>
                            </Nav>
                        </Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Topbar;
```

It also handles outside clicks.

**FontAwesomeLibrary**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faMugHot } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faChevronUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faCoffee);
library.add(faMugHot);
library.add(faTimes);
library.add(faBars);
library.add(faChevronUp);

export default library;
```

I created **FontAwesomeLibrary** according to 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: And what happens when you have multiple links in a navbar, like in almost almost nav bars?

Comment: @Josh, I am just adding his click handler to links that I want to close navbar when clicked, and don't add to those that I don't want to close navbar when clicked

Comment: I used this method, but when the navbar is shown completely on big screens, the text from the links are fading away and then okay again because of the animation of the toggle. Is there a way that I can execute it only when it's in mobile version?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with routing. On a normal webpage a link in a bootstrap nav would cause a new page to load with the nav now closed. Since react doesn't reload the page the nav remains open. In order to fix this you'll need to add the following to each of your `<Link>` elements in the nav: `onClick={this.toggleNavbar}`.